# Fetching manually entered data from CollectionView cells and storing it in an array of objects, using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to iOS and Swift.

I am not able to get the data which I manually entered in multiple UITextFiled present in a cell in my UICollectionView

I want to get the data from each text field continuously as soon as the user starts editing the text and then push it inside the variable in the object.

**Cells Sample - There will be multiple cells**

[image: Screen Shot]

For example, the image provided in the above link is a sample of a cell, this cell holds multiple textfields, labels and buttons

Now I want to get all the data from each cell and store it in an array of object

**My ViewController**

```
extension SampleViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SampleCollectionViewCell;

    return cell;
}

}
```

**My model object class**

```
class Singleton{

static let shared = Singleton()

var list = [CellFields].self

}

class CellFields {

var button1:bool
var button2:bool
var dropdown:String
var field1:String
var field2:String
var field3:String
var label1:String
var label2:String
}
```

**My UICollectionViewCell**

```
class MySampleCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var dropdown: DropDown!
@IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
}
```

I have tried all the delegate methods yet still I am not able to achieve what I want.

**The result I want to achieve looks something similar to this**

```
Singleton.shared.list
[0]
  dropdown = "Dropdown"
  field1 = "Something"
  field2 = "Random"
  field3 = "Another"
  label1 = "Label"
  label2 = "Label2"
  button1 = true
  button2 = false
[1]
  dropdown = "Dropdown1"
  field1 = "Something1"
  field2 = "Random2"
  field3 = "Another3"
  label1 = "Label4"
  label2 = "Label3"
  button1 = false
  button2 = true
...
...
...
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @LingVu I want to store the data which i am entering in the each cell from respective fields and use it in a different controller.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer noted. thanks

Comment: @OnkarKalpavriksha What's your reason for using a presentation technique for form functionality? The collectionview should just show data, if you want to save changes implement the correct delegate methods, which depends on what data you want to save. If you have a textfield in the collectionview for example, make your VC a textFieldDelegate and implement the textDidChange method (google them, this is off the top of my head). Then assign your vc as delegate to the field.

Comment: @kevin thank you for your early reply, but since i will be having multiple fields, labels and buttons i was not able to achieve this textfield delegate method. And what would you suggest me to use instead of collectionview. Yes, this will be something similar to form functionality

Comment: @OnkarKalpavriksha A collectionview is fine for presenting the fields and data, but it doesn't handle any saving/changing. Try making your VC a textfielddelegate, then in your cell create an initialize method with a textfielddelegate parameter, call it when you create the cell and pass the vc (self) to the cell. In the init method you assign the textfield's .delegate to the value of your delegate parameter. With all that your textfield will call certain methods on your vc when the content changes. Now implement those methods (textFieldDidChange IIRC) and do something with the new data.

Comment: @OnkarKalpavriksha You could also put all the textFieldDelegate stuff in the cell, and put a general cellDidChange method in your vc, then pass your vc to the cell and call that cellDidChange method on it when any field changes.

Comment: @kevin i have tried using textfielddelegate method and were able to get the modified text but i have other queries,.... 1) I was not able to get which field it edits and what that field represents.... 2) what if it is a formula field and it gets its value from other fields.... 3) and we have label as well..... 4) Could you also share the code on how to store all the fields in a singleton, so that i can use it throughout the app

Comment: @OnkarKalpavriksha See my answer. For the singleton part, I would strongly recommend you to look into other solutions because that's a huge code smell, you're going to regret it in the future. You can save all the values in the VC, or preferable a separate model, you can put {didSet{}} behind them if you want to update multiple values if one of them changes. But singletons for storage a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create something similar to the following:

```
// create your own delegate type for the cell
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func myTextFieldChanged(_ tf: UITextField) // call when the textfield changes
    func myOtherTextFieldChanged(_ tf: UITextField) // call when the other textfield changes
    func myToggleChanged(_ sw: UISwitch) // call when the switch changes
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private var myTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet private var myOtherTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet private var myToggle: UISwitch!

    private var _delegate: MyCellDelegate? // instance of above protocol type, this will generally be your VC

    func initialize(withDelegate delegate: MyCellDelegate) {
        myTextField.delegate = self
        myOtherTextField.delegate = self
        self._delegate = delegate // a textfield uses a delegate pattern
        self.myToggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged) // a switch uses this target/selector pattern
    }
}

// I like putting delegate implementations in extensions
extension MyCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    // called when a textfield changes
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == myTextField {
            _delegate?.myTextFieldChanged(textField) // call the protocol's method to signal the VC of the change
        }
        if textField == myOtherTextField {
            _delegate?.myOtherTextFieldChanged(textField) // call the protocol's method to signal the VC of the change
        }
    }
}

extension MyCell {
    // @objc is required for the target/selector pattern
    @objc func toggleValueChanged(_ toggle: UISwitch) {
        if toggle == myToggle {
            _delegate?.myToggleChanged(toggle)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your VC's cellForItemAt:

```
let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SampleCollectionViewCell;
cell.initialize(withDelegate: self)
return cell;
```

And also in your VC, make it a `MyCellDelegate` with:

```
extension SampleViewController: MyCellDelegate{
    func myTextFieldChanged(_ tf: UITextField) {
        // save new textfield value
    }
    func myOtherTextFieldChanged(_ tf: UITextField) {
        // save new other textfield value
    }
    func myToggleChanged(_ sw: UISwitch) {
        // save new toggle value
    }
}
```

Ideally, you would create a single method that updates your entire form at once, but that really depends on what kind of data you have and what is optional and whatnot, I'll leave that as a challenge. But at least from this you should be able to get your form working and understand what is going on with all the delegate stuff.

Comment: this is not working. i am not getting an error and at the same time i am not getting the output. I added print statement to check in "extension SampleViewController: MyCellDelegate{"

Comment: @OnkarKalpavriksha  right, you need to set `textField.delegate = self` for every field in your cell. Sorry about htat

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need a singleton to create an array of class objects:

   ```
   let classFieldSets: [ClassFields] = []
   ```
2. Create an init method in your model class:
3. Pass them to the cell via `cellForItemAt` in your SampleViewController extension.

Comment: i don't want to pass data to cell rather i want to fetch data from all cells and store it database.